# CSS3 border radius and bigger rounded div in div

Tags: html, css, border, radius

[image]

I want to make this exapmle in css3 and html5 in div.

thanx for all!

Answer (score 1):

Actually I should not be answering this. SO is for helping you when you are stuck with your code, not for having others write the code for you. But hey, it is Easter, and since it is so easy...

```
div {
    background: black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -150px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: -75px;
    background: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 40px 75px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px 75px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

and a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o004hrqz/

Let me know if you want me to explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

  <style type="text/css">
  .div1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #F00;
    position: relative;
    border-top-left-radius: 40px 75px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px 75px;
  }
  .div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -20px;
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```